# Canonical transformation from Hamiltonian without external source to Hamiltonian with external source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

> Let a system with time-independent Hamiltonian, $H_0(q,p)$ be subjected to an external oscillating field $E_0\sin(wt)$, so that the Hamiltonian becomes $H=H_0(q,p)-qE_0\sin(wt)$. Find a [canonical transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) that causes the Hamiltonian to be transformed from $H_0$ to $H$.

My Work:

Since I know that $H = H_0+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$, I can straight away, plug in $H$, and $H_0$, and compute $F$, which is my generating function. Now this makes my $F$ to be $F=\frac{qE_0\cos(wt)}w$. Now this can't be a generating function. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hint: Use a [type 2 CT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function).

Comment: @Qmechanic: I still cannot understand, how to use it. Have been trying for some time, but still stuck.